# Basketball player indicator random variable question

Tags: probability, random-variables, self-learning

> A certain basketball player practices shooting free throws over and over again. The shots are independent, with probability $ p $ of success. In $ n $ shots, what is the expected number of streaks of $ 7 $ consecutive successful shots? (Note that, for example, $ 9 $ in a row counts as $ 3 $ streaks.)

I do not understand why we cannot use the binomial distribution and answer $ 7 p $ here for the expected shots and then divide by $ 3 $, so the answer is $ \frac { 7 p } 3 $. The actual answer is $ ( n - 6 ) p ^ 7 $.

Comment: *How* is this a question about [tag:self-learning]?

Comment: Among other things, your answer is independent of $n$, which is patently silly,  you'd be saying your expected number of streaks is the exact same no matter how many shots you took!

Comment: The chance of a streak that starts at shot $k$ and continues through shot $(k+6)$ is $p^7.$  There are $(n-6)$ such positions that the streak can start in.  The only way to **painlessly** conclude the problem is to first **study** [this linearity of expectation article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) which includes a proof that the principle holds, **even for dependent events**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k = 7$ to $n$,
let $X_k$ be an indicator r.v that $= 1$ if there is a streak including it and the $6$ preceding numbers and $0$ otherwise.

Then $P(X_k) = p^7$

The expectation of an indicator variable is just the probability of the event it points to, so

$\Bbb E[X_k] = p^7$,

and by linearity of expectation, which holds even if the r.v's are not independent,

$\Bbb E[X] = \Bbb E[X_7] +  \Bbb E[X_8] + \Bbb E[X_9] + ...\Bbb E[X_n] = (n-6)p^7$